# Laravel empty array after array push in php loop

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

here my code :

```
if($difficulty && $course_name) {
        $kanji_course = Course::with('cards')
            ->where('difficulty', $difficulty)
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$course_name.'%')
            ->first();

        $kanji_cards = $kanji_course['cards'];

        if($kanji_cards && $card['targetLang'] && $card['targetLang'] === 'ja' && $card['expression']) {
            $kanji_array = [];
            foreach($kanji_cards as $kanji_card) {
                if(str_contains($card['expression'], $kanji_card['expression'])) {
                    // dd(gettype($kanji_card)); -> "object"
                    array_push($kanji_array, $kanji_card);
                }
            }
            // dd($kanji_array); -> empty array
        }
    }
```

I try to push items in an array, but the array is always empty, unless i put him in the loop.
I tried to use reference "&kanji_card", i tried to use "$kanji_array[] = $kanji_card;" but same problem.

Anyone know why ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you really do `// dd(gettype($kanji_card)); -> "object"` inside that `if` condition? In other words, are you certain your code enters that `if`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely @El_Vanja

Comment: In that case, I don't see how this code could produce that issue.

Comment: Use dd($kanji_courses); after query just check did you have required data? And also share the screenshot

Comment: @MunawarHussian This is an object with 'cards' collection inside

Comment: Show full code or at least a reproducible code.

Comment: Actually you can see the object data by dd method, its for debugging and as per your calling it will only fetch first row which can be directly show in loop no nedd to assign it to other object so try dd and make sure you have data in object then proceed